# I have JS code same thing i have to convert in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have `JS` code, I wants to convert into PHP. I have written but i am not sure. This correct or not. Please anyone check and let me know.

> JS (Node Js)

```
var temp = `${empID}\n${timestamp}\n1\n`;
```

> PHP

```
$temp = nl2br($empID . "\n" . $timestamp . "\n1\n");
```

Comment: Why do you convert newlines to `<br>` in PHP, but not in JavaScript? That causes a different result

Answer (score 0):

what about version without `nl2br`?

```
$temp = $empID . "\n" . $timestamp . "\n1\n";
```